# Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations?

Tags: c#

So I am very new to C# and don't know what this error means, could someone please help me out?

My ammended code is listed below:

```
using System;



namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}

//this won't do anything
/*neither
will this*/



string stringex = "string";
int integerex = 17;
double floatex = 17.5;
char charex = '!';
bool boolex = true;
Console.WriteLine(stringex);
Console.WriteLine(integerex);
Console.WriteLine(floatex);
Console.WriteLine(charex);
Console.WriteLine(boolex);
```

The error line referenced in the title is specifically about the line Console.Writeline(stringex);
Thanks in advance!

I was expecting a list of each value in the terminal but I got an error instead.

Comment: What language version are you using? The code runs fine when I try it.

Comment: there is no error... did you put them in a function?

Comment: There's no error here.However you put your items to class or function...

Comment: please post your entire csproj file             there is too much ambiguity with  language-versions.  C# has "evolved" over the years.

Comment: RIght.  In normal C# (and I don't think this has changed), ALL code needs to be in a class, and your main program needs to be in a function called `Main`.  So, add `class Program {` and `static void Main(string[] args) {` as your second line, and `}` / `}` at the end.

Comment: Works fine for me [Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUH1TABgAJCiBTADxIF4SAichgbjwEspgTPgKBzCmGp0SmAOxtccAPYQARgBsKJAGaKZAQz416EgHQBWKQGMAFprAlzlkfQDkAQntT5MmYpJuPdksEgUUoQAnAAU5NQAlEGYYbwCQlExYepaOtEEsaE2wlQZuCGh3sp5LEA==). Please provide more info.

Comment: it was part of a larger program using the w3schools c# lessons so ill post the whole code here and it might reveal what's wrong

Comment: @granadaCoderhow do I do that

Comment: You're writing code outside the namespace and class block.  Don't do that.

Comment: @LarsTech What do the namespace and class block do, if you wouldn't mind telling me

Comment: Bit of a loaded question, but c# is an object oriented language, so it does everything inside of classes.  Classes organize your related stuff: the properties, the functions, the methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) are somewhat new, since C#9. That's why some of the commenters say things need to be inside classes & methods.

That's no longer strictly true, but since your code does not obey the rule the compiler told you, you're getting [this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8803). If you change the order in your code, such that the top level statements come *before* the namespace, it will compile:
[code in IDEone](https://ideone.com/L0NiZe)

```
using System;

string stringex = "string";
int integerex = 17;
double floatex = 17.5;
char charex = '!';
bool boolex = true;
Console.WriteLine(stringex);
Console.WriteLine(integerex);
Console.WriteLine(floatex);
Console.WriteLine(charex);
Console.WriteLine(boolex);

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Although that exact code is still silly, as it is creating the program entry point, *static void Main,* explicitly - which is the very thing that top level statements are supposed to offload from you, so you can write small scripts without that fluff.

So you might as well put it that way:
[modified code @ IDEone](https://ideone.com/XVypNN)

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

WriteLine("Hello World");
string stringex = "string";
int integerex = 17;
double floatex = 17.5;
char charex = '!';
bool boolex = true;
WriteLine(stringex);
WriteLine(integerex);
WriteLine(floatex);
WriteLine(charex);
WriteLine(boolex);
```

With applied bonus tip: if you make use of the *using static* feature on the System.Console, which is a static class, you won't have to type the name of that class, i.e. Console, all the time when calling its methods such as *WriteLine.* If you call those alot, it will shrink the code a bit. I suggest to not overuse stuff like that, i.e. using static everything "because you can", and then not knowing what's what.